# Can I view my comments if someone deletes them?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

I would like to know whether I can view my comments under someone else's answer to my questions once someone deletes them. I do not know why they were deleted. They seem to constructive to me. Weather post on cognitive sciences was  entirely deleted but I would have liked to view it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't.

The only way a comment can be deleted is by you, or by a diamond moderator. Once it's been deleted, you can't view or undelete it - only moderators have those powers.

If you're *really* fussed about it being deleted, you can bring it up on the per-site Meta, but do bear in mind that comments are intended to be ephemeral and impermanent.

Comment: I think you forgot one of the ways your comment can be deleted. If a user posts an answer, you add a comment, and then the user deletes the answer, your comment is lost.

Comment: @Hohmannfan Obviously if the parent post dies, then your comment goes with it. I was focusing on ways a comment specifically could be deleted, not by indirect routes.